# The dice is rolled 10 times and the results are added with given conditions.

Tags: probability

**Q:**

> A dice has one of the first 6 prime number on each its six sides ,with no two sides having the same number .the dice is rolled 10 times and the results added.the addition is most likely to be closet to

Options given:

**a**-41

**b**  -48

**c**  -60

**d**  - 68

*My Approach:*

I just added all the results of each of the first 6 prime numbers i.e.

$2+3+5+7+11+13=41$

Hence, 41 is the answer.

> Is my approach right? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not agree with @tatan.  The expected value per throw is 41/6, so for 10 throws it is 410/6 which is 68.333...  so, I would pick 68 as the answer

Comment: I have edited my answer..

Comment: Thanks @tatan   I just did not want something incorrect hanging out there, so had to post it.

Comment: @Shailesh-Thanks a lot...I had not read the question properly...

Answer (score 1):

The expected points from each roll of the (unbiased) die is 41/6.

The die is rolled 10 times (this is relevant information that must figure in the calculation). So the expected sum of points is 10*41/6 = 410/6 = 68.333.

So 68 is the best answer, on one natural interpretation of "most likely to be closest to" (which is not a clear expression).

If one repeats this ten-rolls-of-the-die many times, one gets a distribution of results that ranges from a low of 20 to a high of 130. Here one might ask for the mean or average result (68.333). Or one might ask for the median (such that half the results fall below and half above) -- in the case at hand, the median will lie below the mean. Or one might ask for the mode (the single most likely result).

None of these three standard questions about a distribution is well-captured by the expression "most likely to be closest to" which, because it contains two maximands, is inherently unclear -- much like Jeremy Bentham's phrase "the greatest happiness for the greatest number".

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are on the correct path as if it is an unbiased dice the probability of getting each one of the outcomes is equal to-$$p(a)=\frac {1}{6}$$.So,you are likely to get any one on top with equal chance (probability).So,the sum is as you said 2+3+5+7+11+13=41.Now, for 10 throws it is 41/6*10=68.333...(approx.=68)

Here p(a) is the event denoting the probability of getting any one number on rolling the die.